# Xamarin Forms: Help needed with layout on a ListView inside a StackLayout

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create a view that has several controls centered inside a StackLayout.  When I have just one like this:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="Center" >
    <controls:BindablePicker />
</StackLayout>
```

It works fine:
[Centered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztysG.png)

However, when I try to add a ListView, e.g.:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="Center" >
  <controls:BindablePicker />
  <ListView HorizontalOptions="Center" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
          <ViewCell.View>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
              <controls:BindablePicker Title="Length" />
              <controls:BindablePicker Title="Units" />
            </StackLayout>
          </ViewCell.View>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Everything is left justified and takes up the entire screen:
[Left justified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZKJ5.png)

I'd like the widths of all controls to be as short as possible centered on the screen.  Right now I'm using a ListView because I'm binding a list of objects and I thought that would be easier than trying to use a Grid.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

**UPDATE**  I updated my ViewCell to replace the StackLayout with a Grid, then put the ListView inside a grid as follows:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <ListView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Center" SeparatorVisibility="None">
```

This is pretty much what I want, except the top picker is taking up the entire width of the screen, instead of being only as wide as it needs to be and centered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one small difference between your first StackLayout example and the second StackLayout example (the example inside of the ViewCell), and this is causing the trouble you're experiencing:

- The first StackLayout example is `Orientation="Vertical"`
- The second StackLayout example (the example inside of your ViewCell) is `Orientation="Horizontal"`

StackLayouts in Xamarin.Forms only honor the `HorizontalOptions` property when `Orientation="Vertical"`, and only honor the `VerticalOptions` property when `Orientation="Horizontal"`.

This "feature" of StackLayouts is not well documented, and I couldn't find an example link that specifies it. Personally, I learned this fact from an instructor during a Xamarin University class.

To center the controls of the ViewCell, use a Grid layout instead of a StackLayout. Here's An example:

http://www.trsneed.com/customize-xamarin-forms-listview-with-viewcell/

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply!  I'll give this a try and let you know if I can't get it working.

Comment: Please see update above.  I'm closer, but still missing a piece.

Comment: Thanks Ed! When you get a chance, let's mark this question as answered, and move the update to a new question on StackOverflow. This will help any users  in the future with the same initial question, and I'm more than happy to help you with with the Grid!

Comment: Added new question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40880591/xamarin-forms-centering-multiple-different-controls-in-a-layout