# Xamarin Forms: Centering multiple, different controls in a layout?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

My XAML looks like this:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="Center">
  <controls:BindablePicker HorizontalOptions="Center" />
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Center" SeparatorVisibility="None">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
            <ViewCell.View>
              <Grid BackgroundColor="Aqua">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <controls:BindablePicker Title="Length" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="White" />
                <controls:BindablePicker Title="Units" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="White" />
              </Grid>
            </ViewCell.View>
          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
  </Grid>
</StackLayout>
```

Here's what I'm getting:  [Attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNby2.png)

This is pretty much what I want, except I want the content centered within the aqua area so everything is centered horizontally.  I don't mind if the left cell is right justified and the right cell is left justified.

Note that I'm wanting to add other content beneath this, like labels and other grids, all centered on the page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I do not think that you need a row definition in your inner grid since you have only one row.

Secondly for performance sake,do not user "Auto" , just remove the width property from the column definitions. 
By doing this both columns will have the same width... I hope ;)

I think if you made your list view like below then it would fix it, but also try it without HorizontalOptions for the controls.

```
<ListView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Center" SeparatorVisibility="None">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
            <ViewCell.View>
              <Grid BackgroundColor="Aqua">

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition  />
                  <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <controls:BindablePicker Title="Length" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalOptions = "End" />
                <controls:BindablePicker Title="Units"  Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalOptions = "Start" />
              </Grid>
            </ViewCell.View>
          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

**Hint**: The next release of Xamarin.Forms, which is in the alpha channel now, contains a bindable picker so you do not have to user a 3rd party now.

Comment: I think that did it.  Thanks!  Only issue I have now is when the picker is initialized to "Feet", the width is a bit smaller such that when I change it to "Yards" part of the "s" is cutoff.